# How to override past records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table where one field can have the same value in multiple records. For example:

[image]

I would like to select the `EndTime` and `UserId` of each `UserID` once. If there are multiple records with the same `UserID`  I want to select the most recent record and override the past ones.

I'm working with `Sqlite` in python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```sql
SELECT EndTime, userID
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS rn,
          t.* 
     FROM t 
  ) AS tt
 WHERE rn = 1
```

where grouping by `userID` is provided by `PARTITION BY userID`, and picking the recent values is provided through sorting descendingly by `StartTime`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7f0fe5b269b770ca7ba07ef01dd6a34d)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

All you need is aggregation:

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(StartTime) StartTime, EndTime
FROM tablename
GROUP BY UserID;
```

because SQLite will return for each `UserID` the row with the max `StartTime`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=88f065ed32e161e09f2cffd8ad0be063).